# Dynamic colour changes on divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I need help. I can't get javascript to dynamically change colour of the three divs listed in code below. I have pasted the full code below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.box{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
quote 1
</div>
<div class="box">
quote 2
</div>
<div class="box">
quote 3
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var bgcolorlist=new Array( "#ff33cc", "#cc33ff")

$(".box").css("background-color",bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery on `$(".box").css()`, but you haven't linked the library! Add this before your current script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or, simply don't use jQuery at all:

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
}
```